# Is there any range of random initialisation of weights in neural network in classification probelm?

Tags: python, neural-network, feed-forward

I am implementing a neural network which will take 225 input neurons and it has to classify random numbers from 1 to 7. So for this i need 225 random weights for first output. Suggest me what to do? I have to feed this to feed forward neural network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note - I am assuming you are using a basic feed forward neural network with backprop. Please state otherwise if you are not.***

You will essentially need two sets of weights, one set of weights for your hidden layers and one set of weights for your output layers.

Here is a basic function that should explain what I mean:

```
# Initialize a network
def initialize_network(n_inputs, hidden_nodes, n_outputs):
    n_inputs = len(training_data[0]) - 1
    n_outputs = len(set([row[-1] for row in training_data]))

    # Create a blank list to hold the network
    network = []
    # Create your hidden layer
    hidden_layer = [{'weights': [random() for i in range(n_inputs + 1)]} for i in range(hidden_nodes)]
    # Append the hidden layer to your network list
    network.append(hidden_layer)
    # Create the output layer
    output_layer = [{'weights': [random() for i in range(hidden_nodes + 1)]} for i in range(n_outputs)]
    # Append that
    network.append(output_layer)

    # Return the network
    return network
```

A couple of things to remember:

- `hidden_nodes` should be a tunable parameter or specified in your project instructions. The # of hidden nodes is different for everyone
- Your training data will vary in size, but the function above is agnostic of that